# How to Increase Height and Width of Toggle button size of Treeview

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0

I have written a style for Treeview Expander style. I need to increase the size of the toggle button. The toggle button looks very small. The toggle button is like + symbol. Here i have attached my code. Could you please help me.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Grid` as anything inside `Grid` fills entire space by default.

Or, you can use a `ViewBox`.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that is to set a MinWidth And MinHeight.
But be aware it can make other changes to the rest of the treeview